# Getting the error "VEVI: Variable is not properly set" in Eiffel

Tags: iterator, void, notnull, eiffel

I am trying to make an iterator for for a linked_list in Eiffel.

**I am getting this error:** Variable is not set properly.

```
Class: ITERATOR_ON_COLLECTION [E]
Feature: make
Attribute(s): {ITERATOR}.target
Line: 30
```

I know it's because of void safety but I don't know how to fix it. (I set void safety to True and changed the precompiled library to safe version and clean_compile it.)

the following is the class:

```
class
    ITERATOR_ON_COLLECTION [E]

inherit
    ITERATOR [E]

create
    make

feature {NONE} -- Attributes

    collection: LINKED_LIST[E]
    item_index: INTEGER

feature -- initialization

    make(c: LINKED_LIST [E])
        require
            --c /= void
        do
            --  create {COLLECTION} collection.make
            --  create collection.make -- it doesnt work with/without this line 
            collection := c
            item_index := 1
        end

    start
        do
            item_index := 1
        end

    item: STRING
        do
            Result := "hello"
        end

    next
        do
            item_index := item_index + 1
        end

    is_off: BOOLEAN
        do
            Result := True
        end


    do_until (action: PROCEDURE [E]; test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN])
            -- Apply `action' to every item of `target' up to
            -- and including first one satisfying `test'.
            -- (Apply to full list if no item satisfies `test').
        require else
            action_exists: action /= Void
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

    do_while (action: PROCEDURE [E]; test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN])
            -- Apply `action' to every item of `target' up to
            -- and including first one not satisfying `test'.
            -- (Apply to full list if all items satisfy `test').
        require else
            action_exists: action /= Void
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

    until_do (action: PROCEDURE [E]; test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN])
            -- Apply `action' to every item of `target' up to
            -- but excluding first one satisfying `test'.
            -- (Apply to full list if no items satisfy `test'.)
        require else
            action_exists: action /= Void
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

    while_do (action: PROCEDURE [E]; test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN])
            -- Apply `action' to every item of `target' up to
            -- but excluding first one satisfying not `test'.
            -- (Apply to full list if all items satisfy `test'.)
        require else
            action_exists: action /= Void
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

    there_exists (test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN]): BOOLEAN
            -- Is `test' true for at least one item of `target'?
        require else
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

    for_all (test: FUNCTION [E, BOOLEAN]): BOOLEAN
            -- Is `test' true for all items of `target'?
        require else
            test_exists: test /= Void
        do
        end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the class `ITERATOR` it's hard to tell what is the real cause. Here is my guess what happens:

Class `ITERATOR` declares an attribute `target` of an attached type. The attribute has to be set in your creation procedure. Most probably you need to discard the attribute `collection` in your class and use `target` instead. Depending on the attribute's type you may need to redefine it in your class or not.

In terms of efforts it's better to start from void-safe versions of classes right from the beginning and when you switch from a non-void-safe settings to void-safe ones, you may need to make sure that the class types are attached by default (look for a configuration option *"Are types attached by default?"* in projects setting dialog). This option should be set to *True* (this is not done automatically in EiffelStudio prior to 16.11).

A few comments on other parts of the code:

- If an argument type is attached there is no point of checks in the form `arg /= Void`.
- If a precondition `foo` is specified for a feature in a parent class there is no need to repeat it like

  ```
  require else
      foo
  ```

  It can be safely removed. (You can look at the feature flat (or flat short) form to see that the parent's precondition is still there.)
- If comments of redefined features are not changed, they can be replaced with

  ```
  -- <Precursor>
  ```

  This way any changes in parent's versions will be automatically reflected in redeclarations (again have a look at the flat form).